# Schwarzschild metric - proof that any 2-sphere lies in a single hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

Wald derives the Schwarzschild metric assuming static spacetime (the spacetime is foliated into hypersurfaces $\Sigma_t$ orthogonal to a timelike Killing field $\xi^a$) and spherically symmetric spacetime (the spacetime isometry group contains a subgroup isomorphic to $SO(3)$). In this step he finds that any 2-sphere lies wholly in a single hypersurface, so he can take as coordinates time, the two-dimensional spherical coordinates, and radius.

> If a spacetime is both static and spherically symmetric, and if the static Killing field $\xi^a$ is unique (as we shall assume), then $\xi^a$ must be orthogonal to the orbit 2-spheres. Namely, if $\xi^a$ is unique, it must be invariant under all the rotational isometries. However, this requires its projection onto any orbit sphere to vanish, since a nonvanishing vector field on a sphere cannot be invariant under all rotations. Thus the orbit spheres lie wholly within the hypersurfaces, $\Sigma_t$, orthogonal to $\xi^a$.
> Convenient coordinates on the spacetime may be chosen as follows: We select a sphere on $\Sigma=\Sigma_0$ and chose spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ on it. We "carry" this spherical coordinates to the other spheres of $\Sigma$ by means of geodesics orthogonal to the two-sphere. Provided that $\nabla_a r \neq 0$, we chose $(r, \theta, \phi)$ as coordinates in $\Sigma_t$ and finally we chose $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ as coordinates for the spacetime. In these coordinates, the metric of an arbitrary static, spherically symmetric spacetimes takes the simple form
> $$ ds^2 = -f(r)dt^2 + h(r)dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2\theta\phi^2)$$
> where $h$ and $f$ are arbitrary functions and, given the area $A$ of a sphere, $r$ is defined as $$r=(A/4\pi)^{1/2}$$

While in a space like $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ this seems obvious to me, in a general manifold I would like to see rigorous proof of these two facts:

1. Why is $\xi^a$ orthogonal to the 2-spheres?
   I would like to see an explanation of this sentence: *Namely, if $\xi^a$ is unique, it must be invariant under all the rotational isometries*
   Why should the Killing field $\xi^a$ be invariant under the isometries? The metric is invariant under isometries but why does he require also the Killing field to be invariant under isometries?
2. Why does the fact that $\Sigma_t$ and the 2-spheres are orthogonal to $\xi^a$ mean that the 2-spheres lie into $\Sigma_t$? While this is intuitive with the euclidean inner product, it doesn't seem obvious to me with a general spacetime metric.

Comment: Isn't question 1 answered by the sentence that starts "However, this requires its projection..."?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert my questions is about that sentence: why we require the the killing field to be invariant under isometries? I will add this to the question.

Comment: For Question 1, the answer is "if $\xi^a$ was not invariant under the rotational isometries, then applying the rotational isometries to the spacetime would yield a distinct timelike Killing vector field $(\xi')^a$ for the spacetime.  But we are assuming that $\xi^a$ is unique."  I will think more about Question 2 before I post an answer.

Comment: I understand: the isometries leave the metric unchanged, so also the Killing field must remain unchanged if it is unique. I would like to a formal proof of this using the definition of Killing field and isometry. I don't want seem too pedantic but I asked this question also to get more practical with technicality of differential geometry.